# detect memory leak in typescript application

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have created vscode extension using typescript. I use vscode editor to write typescript code and run typescript application. I am observing memory leak. How can I debug this?

Comment: Use a memory profiler? I don't know about debugging VS Code extensions, but you can connect Chrome to debug NodeJS programs, and Chrome has memory profiling tools.